Pytest File Name is giving me Traceback file frozen runpy & boostrap & framework python error ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'Crypto' on MacOS
I'm trying to run tests in python files that have been built on the back of the Cairo programming language. But, when I run python3 -m pytest /test_name.py I get the following traceback error. It seems something has mocked up my pytest after I installed some crypto module some time ago.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  ...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(pytest.console_main())
 ...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  ...
    from Crypto import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'


Can you please provide the code and full traceback

I cannot provide the code as it is confidential, but I have attached the error as a gist: Traceback Error

The 'Crypto' error was raised in the eth_keyfile module at line 21.
The error passes all the way back up the chain( in reversed order) -

eth_account/account.py
eth_account/__init__.py
web3/__init__.py
pytest core files in config and
pluginmanager

To resolve the issue -
pip install pycryptodome

The error you're encountering is caused by a missing dependency Crypto. The Crypto module being referenced in eth_account/account.py is part of the pycryptodome library.The eth_account module used to rely on the now-obsolete PyCrypto library, which provided cryptographic functionalities under the Crypto namespace.

It's easy to get confused because pycryptodome utilizes Crypto namespace . If they didn't, one would naturally search for and find the Crypto package on PyPI!

That did not work. Is there a more holistic process than only pip installing pycryptodome.  For instance do I need to uninstall anything.  Or install stuff in order?

Apologies for the delay. Is the error still present? If yes, please try rerunning the project or running the file via command line
